# Style question: keep static methods in class or outside?

Tags: python, pip, python-3.6

I have a class and some methods that I would like to turn into a library. The library relies on a single class, Class. Class has quite a few static methods. These could be moved outside of the Class file.

If I want to turn this into a package, how should I place everything? Should I have one file which has the class, and the methods with static decorators? Or should I move the static methods to a separate file? I know both are functionally equivalent, but I was wondering about generally accepted practice.

In which case it is better to do one versus the other?

Comment: Both approaches are valid. It will mostly come down to personal preference.

Comment: For this amount of functions, I would personally just keep it all in a single code file.

Comment: do whatever you want. If you keep it in one file then you have already module.

Comment: You can have a look at the code repositories of existing python packages ([`scikit-learn`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/tree/master/sklearn) for example) for some inspiration on how to organize your code files.

Comment: comes down your own personal style..personally I like to keep class methods in the same file as the class definition

Answer (score 2):

a library (package) `!=` a file (module) `!=` a class. That is, you can also have one file with a class and a bunch of functions. Which is probably the best in your case.

Static method make sense when you either have a great amount of functions, so you need namespacing, or you plan to exploit inheritance and dynamic binding. In your case, they don't provide much value.

Comment: Hi, I would like to have this be pip-installable, so I understand I need to create a package for that to be the case.

Comment: "package" in terms of packaging doesn't have to be a Python package; that is, it can consist of a single file. But yes, it's conceptually simpler if you really do make a package. The process is explained in much detail at https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/.